# Moving Database SQL Server 2012 to 2008/R2

Tags: sql-server, migration

I'm planning to move a Large Database from SQL Server 2012 to 2008/R2. I tried the scripting thing, it works on a small-medium type of database but not on Large database w/c is about a hundred MB. Any tips on how can I make this? Or Is it recommended to do this for a Large Databases?

Comment: Downgrading is always a pain. The question has an answer that I have practically tried - script out the database **schema ONLY** thereby creating a shell and then use **BCP OUT and BULK  INSERT** to move the data in lower version. Read Aaron's comment as well - if you have new features enabled or inuse, they wont work.

Comment: Hi @Kin but it is recommended for a large databases? I mean for example I have 10,000 rows on 1 table, will it copy all rows and don't miss anything? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for large database, if you script out **along with data**, the script generated will be unmanagable by SSMS or anyother cmdline utility (sqlcmd) as well. The approach I described is very well suited for such things.

Comment: Hi @Kin I run all the query and the steps correctly, no errors actually it shows me some rows affected(sign of successful query for me) but when I go to my SS2008 there's no data added to the blank database that I created on SS2008. Help me please.